# How to combine two different queries to get one output

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the below two queries to see changes within table per_assignments and per_supervisor for columns locat_id,org_id, mng_id.

```sql
with asg_loc_dep as (
  select person_id,
         prev_start_dt,
         start_dt, 
         loc_old,
         loc_new,
         org_new,
         org_old
  from   (
    select person_id,
           locat_id loc_new,
           org_id org_new,
           start_dt, 
           lag(locat_id) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) loc_old,
           lag(org_id) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) org_old, 
           lag(start_dt) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) prev_start_dt, 
           case start_dt when 1 + lag(end_dt) over (partition by person_id order by start_dt) 
           then 1 end flag
    from   per_assignments
  )
  where  flag = 1
  and (loc_new <> loc_old or org_new <> org_old)
)
```

```sql
with asg_asg as (
  select person_id,
         prev_start_dt,
         start_dt, 
         new_mgr,
         mngid_old
  from   (
    select person_id,
           mng_id new_mgr,
           start_dt, 
           lag(mng_id) over (partition by assignment_id order by start_dt) mngid_old,
           lag(start_dt) over (partition by assignment_id order by start_dt) prev_start_dt, 
           case start_dt when 1 + lag(end_dt) over (partition by assignment_id order by start_dt) 
           then 1 end flag
    from   per_supervisor
  )
  where flag = 1
  and (mngid_old<>new_mgr)
)
```

I am getting the right results individually, is there a way to combine these two queries into one to get the below output structure :

```
person_id  prev_start_dt start_dt loc_old  loc_new org_new org_old   mngid_old    new_mgr
```

the common link between both these queries is the person_id. if i use union, what will i pass for the left out columns, also if for the same date -prev_start_dt and start_dt  there is a change in loc_new and new_mgr, then it should come in 1 row. with union it will come in 2 rows.

sample fiddle in only the 1st query

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3b74f9c4f8371ad23bbf53dcbe41f67

```
WITH loc_dep AS 
( 
       SELECT person_id, 
              prev_start_dt, 
              start_dt, 
              --assignment_id, 
              loc_old, 
              loc_new, 
              org_old, 
              org_new 
       FROM   ( 
                       SELECT   person_id, 
                                assignment_id, 
                                location_id                                                                           loc_new,
                                organization_id                                                                       org_new,
                                effective_start_date                                                                  start_dt,
                                Lag(location_id) OVER (partition BY person_id ORDER BY effective_start_date)          loc_old,
                                Lag(organization_id) OVER (partition BY person_id ORDER BY effective_start_date)      org_old,
                                Lag(effective_start_date) OVER (partition BY person_id ORDER BY effective_start_date) prev_start_dt,
                                CASE effective_start_date 
                                         WHEN 1 + Lag(effective_end_date) OVER (partition BY person_id ORDER BY effective_start_date) THEN 1
                                END flag 
                       FROM     per_all_assignments_m paam 
                       WHERE    paam.person_id = '300000010518043' 
                       AND      paam.system_person_type = 'EMP' 
                       AND      paam.assignment_status_type = 'ACTIVE' 
                       AND      paam.assignment_type = 'E' ) 
       WHERE  flag = 1 
       AND    ( 
                     loc_new <> loc_old 
              OR     org_new <> org_old)) , 
              with mgr_compare AS 
( 
                SELECT DISTINCT person_id, 
                                prev_start_dt, 
                                start_dt, 
                                mngr_new, 
                                mngr_old 
                FROM            ( 
                                         SELECT   person_id, 
                                                  manager_id                                                                                 mngr_new,
                                                  effective_start_date                                                                       start_dt,
                                                  effective_end_date                                                                         end_date,
                                                  lag(manager_id) OVER ( partition BY assignment_id ORDER BY effective_start_date)           mngr_old,
                                                  lag(effective_start_date) OVER ( partition BY assignment_id ORDER BY effective_start_date) prev_start_dt,
                                                  CASE effective_start_date 
                                                           WHEN 1 + lag(effective_end_date) OVER (partition BY assignment_id ORDER BY effective_start_date) THEN 1
                                                  END flag 
                                         FROM     per_assignment_supervisors_f pasf 
                                         WHERE    pasf.person_id = '300000010518043') 
                WHERE           flag = 1 
                AND             ( 
                                                mngr_new <> mngr_old )) 
SELECT mgr_compare.person_id 
FROM   mgr_compare, 
       loc_dep 
WHERE  loc_dep.person_id = mgr_compare.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put both CTEs in the same query, and then `join` the results on `person_id`:

```
with 
    asg_loc_dep as (
        select 
            person_id, 
            prev_start_dt, 
            start_dt, 
            loc_old, 
            loc_new, 
            org_new,
            org_old
        from ( ... )
        where ...
    ),
    asg_asg as (
        select 
            person_id, 
            prev_start_dt, 
            start_dt, 
            new_mgr,
            mngid_old
        from (...)
        where ...
    )
select 
    l.person_id,
    l.prev_start_dt,
    l.start_dt,
    l.loc_old,  
    l.loc_new, 
    l.org_new, 
    l.org_old,
    a.mngid_old,
    a.new_mgr
from asg_loc_dep l
inner join asg_asg a on a.person_id = l.person_id
```

Comment: I am getting an ORA-00903: invalid table name
 error

Comment: @Sree: (1) I shorten your query by replacing some part of it with `...`, did you put it back before running it? (2) On which line or which part of the query do you get that error?

Comment: I have updated the question with the query that is giving me an error.....

Comment: @Sree: there should be only one `with` keyword, at the beginning of the query. You have two. Please see my sample query.